# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined. JQuery JCrop issue when selecting croparea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

i'm using JCrop and are having a *very* annoying moment where i just cannot get this ui undefined thing out of this world :(

I have done exactly the same as this fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fbaAW/1/), and this one.. works like a charm....

Here is the order i'm loading the script files :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<script src="photoAppScripts/globalscripts.js"></script> // JCrop logic goes here..
```

Here is the HTML which ... should have worked.

```
<img id="cropbox" class="left" height="auto" width="auto" src="" />
    <div class="container left">
        <div id="Image4" class="Image1 image clip3">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%">
                <use xlink:href="#fullHex" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is how i load the images as source (WORKS!)
I have to initiate the JCrop first since i'm loading the source of the image and the background source of the background from a $http GET call.. But.. that works like it should..

```
$('#cropbox').attr('src', trimmedResult);
$('#Image4').css('background-image', 'url(' + trimmedResult + ')');
initJcrop();
```

Here is initJcrop function in GlobalScripts.JS:

```
function initJcrop() {

var jcrop_api;

jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
    jQuery.browser.msie = false;
    jQuery.browser.version = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
        jQuery.browser.msie = true;
        jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
    }
})();

$('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    onSelect: showCoords,
    onChange: showCoords,
    bgOpacity: .4,
    aspectRatio: 1,
}, function() {
    jcrop_api = this;
});

function showCoords(c) {

    var $this = jcrop_api.ui.holder;
    var original = $this.prev();
    var preview = original.parent().find(".image");

    var oH = original.height();
    var oW = original.width();

    var pH = preview.height();
    var pW = preview.width();

    var sH = c.h;
    var sW = c.w;

    var differenceH = pH - sH;
    var differenceW = pW - sW;

    var rW = pW / c.w;
    var rH = pH / c.h;

    preview.css("background-size", (oW * rW) + "px" + " " + (oH * rH) + "px");
    preview.css("background-position", rW * Math.round(c.x) * -1 + "px" + " " + rH * Math.round(c.y) * -1 + "px");
}
```

}

The CSS is exactly like the fiddle example above...

Anyone got any tip for me on this one ? I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Well.. after much head-banging and tearing my hair off... This question deserves an answer, no matter how obvious it is..

A warning goes out too :) Be VERY careful when you are using "this" and in which context you are using it.. "this" in one context, might ofcourse... be something else in another contecxt.. but most of us know that..

Well.. just a reminder to myself.. be careful of this and $this and when to use it :)

Instead... refer to the object itself to be certain.. ex.

```
var $this = $('#cropbox').ui.holder;
```